Old database .DAT extension
I'm trying to retrieve information from a .DAT file created with an old database that I can't figure out what it is. No program can detect the database type. I can see people's information in text, but what I need is their registration number and I can't identify that.
I've tried several sites that analyze files but without success. Some information in other banks in the same system I was able to retrieve the text information using a Python script, but I need to know at least each person's registration number to be able to link the other information with the correct registrations.
